# Can’t link Android projects in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I can’t link Android projects in Eclipse.

I get a `VerifyError`, and some can’t find class warnings, which I assume means that it’s not getting the library.

I’m using project `properties > Java Build Path > Projects.`

I can get it to work by referencing the other projects jar. Then setting the source attach so that I can step through the code, but this is a much uglier way of setting the projects up because linking to source and linking to the jar doesn’t allow the use of path variables. So the next person to pick up this project is going to be really confused when the project doesn’t work for them.

1. Is it possible to directly link projects?
2. Is it possible to use path variables to reference jars and source
   attachments?

It’s so easy to do in Flash Builder…

Also, when I change anything in properties > Android then hit okay, when I open properties > Android the changes have been reverted, what's that about?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if an android project can reference a "library" project, the answer is yes; open the properties for the main android project and select Android menu and then at the bottom half of the screen, you can Add your library project to your main project. Note that the "library" project should be set as a library project (same UI allows you to set a project as library)

HTH,
Ali.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're talking about a library project that you have in your eclipse workspace.

go to properties -> Android

on the bottom half of the screen you should see a "Library" pane.

click add and point it to your library that's in your workspace that you want to add.

click apply afterwards.

i'd remove what you added in that library pane that you're talking about. that's for jar libraries that you've added to your project's libs folder.